Does updating password policy using PAM force existing users to change their password in the next login?
I plan to configure PAM config files on a SUSE server with the rule below:
Current rule is:
password  required pam_cracklib.so dcredit=-1 ucredit=-1 ocredit=-1 lcredit=0 minlen=9

Rule after change will be:
password  required pam_cracklib.so dcredit=-1 ucredit=-1 ocredit=-1 lcredit=0 minlen=16

The minlen will be increased and there are many existing users with current password lengths smaller than the new minimal length.
After the PAM configuration and restart of the server, will existing users have trouble logging in or be forced to change their current passwords?
I would also appreciate any official documentation to confirm your answer if you don't mind sharing your knowledge.
Thank you.

The "password" section of PAM only applies when authentication tokens (passwords) are actually being changed; e.g. when a user runs the passwd command or when their password has expired and they need to set a new one.
It does not pro-actively force a change or block older passwords because it's not called during a login.
If you want to force a user to change their password on next login then you need to expire the existing password; e.g with passwd -e.

Assume the new rule is placed in the SUSE file /etc/pam.d/common-password.
If another command, not passwd, with its PAM configuration file includes this common-password.
For example, we use command crond.
PAM configuration file for crond is /etc/pam.d/crond with this line:
`password include common-password`.

When a user with current short password runs crond, do they need to change the password?

crond does not include password-change functionality, so it will just ignore any PAM configuration lines starting with the keyword password. But in practice, crond needs to run as root because it needs to be able to create child processes on different user accounts to run each user's cronjobs as them, so trying to start crond as a non-root user is not going to succeed anyway.

@Dr.Doofenshmirtz  No.  The password entries in PAM will never force a password change.
